# JAXB generate weired html tag

Tags: java, jaxb

Small question about JAXB auto code generation.

For the comment part, it will generate some schema like following:

```
&lt;element name="partner_system_priority" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int"/>
```

I want to know why JAXB dont make > as a &gt?

Br,
Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comment is generated for `javadoc` tool.
So this comment will be a part of HTML page after javadoc generation.
It is enough to replace only first `less then` (`<`) symbol with `&lt;` in HTML report.

Both

```
&lt;element name="partner_system_priority" 
   type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int"/>
```

and

```
&lt;element name="partner_system_priority" 
   type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int"/&gt;
```

will be interpreted by browser as

```
<element name="partner_system_priority" 
       type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int"/>
```

So, no reason to do redundant replacement